# Is there a theory of algebraic universal algebra?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra

An algebraic group is a group that is also an algebraic variety.  There is also a theory of algebraic monoids.  Is there are version of universal algebra that incorporates these examples, and other classes of algebras given by equations that are simultaneously algebraic varieties?

(I found it hard to do searches on this, since variety has a more general meaning in universal algebra, as does polynomial.  I guessed they would be called "algebraic algebras" in analogy with "algebraic groups", but this term means something else.  There's also a field of "universal algebraic geometry", which is a different kind of generalization of algebraic geometry with coefficients more general than commutative rings.)

**Edit**: Just to clarify, I'm interested in results that meaningfully exploit properties of algebraic varieties.  I'm aware of the general theory of universal algebra inside a category, a la Lawvere theories.

Comment: There are also algebraic lattices, but I imagine you don't want this either.  What you want seems to concern certain subsets of (let's say) a product algebra and ask whether they intersect a related sub universe of the product algebra.  I have not seen such literature. Short of asking Keith Kearnes, I think your best bet is looking at algebraic subuniverses.  Gerhard "Until I Bet Something Better" Paseman, 2018.09.11.

Comment: There is a notion of "group object" in a category (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object), yielding algebraic groups when specified to suitable categories of varieties. Possibly there are similar notions for other structures.

Comment: You can define a "X object" for any variety in the universal algebra sense, and there's a general notion of Lawvere theory for an arbitrary category.  I'm specifically curious about the "X objects" in the category of algebraic varieties or schemes.  The theory of algebraic groups is much deeper than the theory of "group objects" in general, and I'm curious if there any results of any depth in this more general setting.

Comment: For example, an algebraic group that's a complete variety has to be abelian, which is an interesting interaction of algebra and geometry.

Comment: Operads are essentially the same thing universal algebras, and the former term is more commonly used in category-theoretical/topological/geometric settings, so searching for "algebraic operads" may be more fruitful. For example, here is the first result I found: http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf

Comment: @arsmath you want connected as well.

Comment: @ItaiBar-Natan If Wikipedia is to be believed, operads don't allow equations with repeated or missing variables, so there is no group operad.